# Mac OS X 10.8 add startup command

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion

How can I add several terminal commands to be run on every start of my Mac OS X 10.8 ?

sample command (Starts MySQL):

"sudo /usr/local/zend/bin/zendctl.sh start-mysql"

is there any tool to simplify such tasks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, this would be done using the [launchd](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html) daemon.  There is a gui interface that can help you set things up called [lingon here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lingon/files/)

Comment: Thanks jgritty, I also found this online tool to generate plists:
http://launched.zerowidth.com/